# MUI DateCalendar With Luxon Adapter Start Week On Sunday

Tags: luxon, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

Recently, Luxon added support for [localized week information](https://github.com/moment/luxon/pull/1454). I updated my version of Luxon to the latest release that contains this update, `3.4.4` but when opening up the calendar, the week still starts on Monday instead of Sunday.

I would assume that the `LuxonAdapter` would pick up the changes and use the localized week data but it doesn't seem to be any different.

My `package.json` has the latest versions of both libraries:

```json
"@mui/x-date-pickers": "^7.0.0-alpha.0",
"luxon": "^3.4.4",
```

Then, in my `App.tsx` I add the `LocalizationProvider` with the `LuxonAdapter`:

```js
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { AdapterLuxon } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterLuxon";

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon}>
    <Outlet />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Lastly, the `DateCalendar` component:

```js
import { DateTime } from "luxon";
import { DateCalendar } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";

const [calendarValue, setCalendarValue] = useState<DateTime | null>(DateTime.now());

<DateCalendar
    value={calendarValue}
    onChange={setCalendarValue}
    views={["day"]}
    disablePast
    sx={{ m: 0 }}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you currently have:

```
Client Application
│
├─ package.json
│  ├─ "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^7.0.0-alpha.0"
│  └─ "luxon": "^3.4.4"
│
├─ App.tsx
│  ├─ LocalizationProvider (with LuxonAdapter)
│  └─ Outlet
│
└─ DateCalendar Component
   ├─ DateTime from "luxon"
   └─ DateCalendar from "@mui/x-date-pickers"
```

Verify first that [Luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon) is configured with the correct locale that starts the week on Sunday. If your locale is set to one where the week traditionally starts on Monday, Luxon will follow that setting.

```js
import { Settings } from 'luxon';

// Set the locale globally for Luxon
Settings.defaultLocale = 'your-locale'; // Replace 'your-locale' with the appropriate locale code
```

If the LuxonAdapter does not automatically pick the start of the week from Luxon settings, you might need to configure it explicitly. But I do not see a way to do this directly in [`@mui/x-date-pickers`](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/).

[`mui/material-ui` issue 30591](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/30591#issuecomment-1758587765) proposes, on a similar issue referenced by [`moment/luxon` issue 1447](https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/1447) (the very issue your [`moment/luxon` PR 1454](https://github.com/moment/luxon/pull/1454) fixes)

```js
function adapterLuxonFactory(weekStartsOn: number) {
  class Adapter extends AdapterLuxon {
    private weekStartsOn = weekStartsOn;

    /** Controls the header of the calendar month view. */
    public getWeekdays = () => {
      const weekdays = Info.weekdaysFormat("narrow", { locale: this.locale });
      const start = weekdays.slice(0, this.weekStartsOn - 1);
      const end = weekdays.slice(this.weekStartsOn - 1);
      return [...end, ...start];
    };

    /** Controls the day buttons of the calendar month view. */
    getWeekArray = (date: DateTime) => {
      const startOfMonth = date.startOf("month");
      const endOfMonth = date.endOf("month");
      const firstDayOfMonth = startOfMonth.weekday;

      const startOfWeek = startOfMonth.minus({
        days: (firstDayOfMonth - this.weekStartsOn + 7) % 7,
      });

      const endOfWeek = endOfMonth
        .plus({ days: 6 - endOfMonth.weekday + this.weekStartsOn })
        .endOf("day");

      const { days } = endOfWeek.diff(startOfWeek, "days").toObject();

      const weeks: DateTime[][] = [];
      new Array<number>(Math.round(days ?? 0))
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, i) => i)
        .map((day) => startOfWeek.plus({ days: day }))
        .forEach((v, i) => {
          if (i === 0 || (i % 7 === 0 && i > 6)) {
            weeks.push([v]);
            return;
          }

          weeks[weeks.length - 1].push(v);
        });

      return weeks;
    };
  }

  return Adapter;
}

export function LocalizationProvider({
  children,
}: {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}): JSX.Element {
  const { weekStartsOn } = useYourOwnDatabase();

  return (
    <MuiLocalizationProvider dateAdapter={adapterLuxonFactory(weekStartsOn)}>
      {children}
    </MuiLocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

The custom adapter factory function `adapterLuxonFactory` takes a `weekStartsOn` parameter (number representing the day the week starts on, with `1` for Monday, `2` for Tuesday, up to `7` for Sunday). That function is used in the `LocalizationProvider` to make sure the entire calendar component respects the specified start of the week.

To integrate this solution into your current setup, you would replace, for testing, the standard `LuxonAdapter` with this custom adapter, by modifying the `LocalizationProvider` in your `App.tsx` to use this custom adapter.
Make sure you provide the correct `weekStartsOn` value when initializing the adapter. For starting the week on Sunday, this would be `7`.

---

I also see [`mui/mui-x` issue 9984](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/9984#issuecomment-1787547736), which says:

> Since 2021, I've been using the workaround noted in [`mui/material-ui-pickers` issue 1270](https://github.com/mui/material-ui-pickers/issues/1270) to force Luxon to use Sunday as the first day of the week and just noticed that it no longer works.
>
> ```js
> import {Info} from 'luxon';
> import LuxonUtils from '@date-io/luxon';
>
> class CustomLuxonUtils extends LuxonUtils {
>   getWeekdays() {
>     // need to copy the existing, and use Info to preserve localization
>     const days = [...Info.weekdaysFormat('narrow', this.locale)];
>     // remove Sun from end of list and move to start of list
>     days.unshift(days.pop());
>     return days;
>   }
>
>   getWeekArray(date) {
>     const endDate = date
>       .endOf('month')
>       // if a month ends on sunday, luxon will consider it already the end of the week
>       // but we need to get the _entire_ next week to properly lay that out
>       // so we add one more day to cover that before getting the end of the week
>       .plus({days: 1})
>       .endOf('week');
>     const startDate = date
>       .startOf('month')
>       .startOf('week')
>       // must subtract 1, because startOf('week') will be Mon, but we want weeks to start on Sun
>       // this is the basis for every day in a our calendar
>       .minus({days: 1});
>
>     const {days} = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days').toObject();
>
>     const weeks = [];
>     new Array(Math.round(days))
>       .fill(0)
>       .map((_, i) => i)
>       .map(day => startDate.plus({days: day}))
>       .forEach((v, i) => {
>         if (i === 0 || (i % 7 === 0 && i > 6)) {
>           weeks.push([v]);
>           return;
>         }
>
>         weeks[weeks.length - 1].push(v);
>       });
>
>     // a consequence of all this shifting back/forth 1 day is that you might end up with a week
>     // where all the days are actually in the previous or next month.
>     // this happens when the first day of the month is Sunday (Dec 2019 or Mar 2020 are examples)
>     // or the last day of the month is Sunday (May 2020 or Jan 2021 is one example)
>     // so we're only including weeks where ANY day is in the correct month to handle that
>     return weeks.filter(w => w.some(d => d.month === date.month));
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> I was able to fix it by adding an override for the startOfWeek method as follows:
>
> ```js
> startOfWeek = (value: DateTime) => {
>     return value.startOf('week').minus({ days: 1 });
> }
> ```

This is discussed in [`mui/mui-x` issue 10805](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/10805): "`[pickers]` Support changing start of week day on AdapterLuxon"

> The clean fix will be merged in the v7 alpha branch.

This is [`mui/mui-x` PR 10964](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/pull/10964)

Comment: Very well-explained answer to the issue. It helps me a lot. Great thanks!!